# Is there an XML schema for drawing histogram and line graphs - with XSLTs already available?

Tags: xml, xslt, graph, charts

I'm trying to generate SVG-based histograms / line-graphs from data I have in another format.
Before I try and re-invent an inferior wheel - is there already a well-used simple-to-use , fit-for-purpose XML format with XSLTs that can do the graphing part for me ?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether http://www.dpawson.co.uk/graph2svg/ does what you want. The stylesheets are XSLT 2.0 however so you will need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML.

Comment: Looks good - but my Czech isn't so good....so it'll take me a bit of time to check!